# Sum of Angles in a Hilbert space

Tags: reference-request

Given three vectors $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$ in a Hilbert space Hthe follwing is true
$$\angle(v_1,v_2)+\angle(v_2,v_3)\geq \angle(v_1,v_3).$$

It tried to substitute $\angle(v_1,v_2) = cos^{-1}\frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{\Vert v_1 \Vert \Vert v_2 \Vert}$ but I could not show the resulting inequality. What is the name of the inequality and do you know reference that one can cite in an article?

Comment: You can assume the Hilbert space is $\mathbb R^3$ (spanned by the vectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG we can assume that we are in three space as mentioned above and that the vectors have length $ 1$. With the origin $O$ they span a triangular prism $OABC$.  Then the area of say $OAB$ is less than the sum of that of $OAC$ and that of $OCB$.  If we express these areas in term of the sines of the angles, we get an inequality which soon gives the required result.

Answer (score 3):

The angle (in $[0,\pi]$) corresponds to geodesic distance on the unit sphere. This is just the triangle inequality. No reference needed.